# Function for key values using a vector of lists

Tags: c++, list, vector

I'm having trouble implementing a c++ function and would require your help. Let me try to explain the goal of my function. I have two vectors vector  keys and vector > values as private variables of my class.First I am trying to fill the vector keys with values of keys. Next I am trying to fill the vector values with a list of values for a particular key. In the index that will contain the key in my keys vector the same index will carry a set of int values in a list associated with the keys in my values vector.
For Example 
insert(2,4)
insert(2,6)
Now the first index of my keys vector will contain 2 and the first index of my values vector will have a list that contains 4 and 6. Here is what I have come up with by I keep getting segmentation fault. Can you help me achieve this, especially how to store the values. Here is my code for the insert function.

```
Class A1
 {  
public:
     {
      for (unsigned int i=0;i<keys.size();i++)
      {
        if (keys.at(i)==key)
        {
          return;
        }
      }
      keys.push_back(key);
    /*  for (unsigned int i=0;i<keys.size();i++)
      {
        if(keys[i]==key)
        {
          values[i].push_back(value);
        }
      }*/
    }

private:
  vector<int>keys;
  vector<list<int>> values;
}
```

The code that I have commented out using /* */ is the part that is giving me the error.

Comment: Is that supposed to be a constructor? It's just a block of code inside a `Class A1` with capital `C`? I'm confused. Please post proper code. Try to make a [mcve].

Comment: Why are you not just using a `map<int, list<int> >` instead of two vectors? Is the point of this "implementing it yourself"? If so then using STL containers like vector and list doesnt make much sense to me.

Comment: It's for a college project, Can't use map I have to use a combination and lists.